# Vscode - How do I constrain some snippets to blank files only?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am creating some snippets to `.tex` files. However, I would like some of these snippets to appear only if my document is blank/empty.

It is possible to create a conditional to check it? It would be something like that:

```
"Example": {
  "prefix": "ex",
  "body": [
    "Just one example"
  ],
  "description": "Example",
  "conditional": if-is-a-blank-file
}
```

Obviously, "conditional" is just a pretend. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a newly opened file?  Or could it be one that had text which was deleted?

Comment: why? Just give them a special prefix `bfxyz` for `blank file xyz`

Comment: @Mark It is a newly opened file. But it could be applied for one whose text was deleted.

Comment: @rioV8 I intend to apply the snippet without necessarily giving a name to the file.

Comment: No, give the snippet a special name/prefix

Comment: I asked because there are `canUndo` and `canRedo` context clauses which would both be `false` for a newly opened file.  But might not be for a file with deleted text of course.  I see no other context clause that indicates an empty file.

Comment: @rioV8, No. Your solution is not convenient for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Mark I see... It is good, is it possible to create a snippet based on these context clauses?

Comment: I tried making a keybinding to insert a snippet with a `when` clause using the `canUndo` and `canRedo` contexts.  But those values don't seem to work as one would expect that they would from their names.  So I am probably stumped.